# Stationary Distribution of a Markov Chain from Conditionals

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, ergodic-theory

I am considering a Gibbs sampling algorithm where I want to start from a given
pair of conditional distributions $f(y \mid x)$ and $f(x \mid y)$ and form a
Markov chain by sampling $Y_t \sim f(y \mid X_t)$ and $X_{t+1} \sim f(x \mid Y_t)$.

I am willing to make the following assumptions to try to establish that the stationary distribution exists:

1. Both $f(y \mid x)$ and $f(x \mid y)$ are densities with respect to Lebesgue
   measure and are compactly supported.
2. For both densities we have $\epsilon \le f(y \mid x) \le \epsilon^{-1}$ and $\epsilon \le f(x \mid y) \le \epsilon^{-1}$.

I guess it should follow from this that the chain is irreducible, aperiodic, and
recurrent, hence the stationary distribution should exist. But when I try to
derive it, I seem to get intro trouble, which makes me doubt the reasoning I
gave. I tried checking directly by trying to find $f(x,y)$ such that

$$
  f(x', y') = \int f(x,y) \, f(x \mid y') \, f(y' \mid x') \ dx \ dy
$$

but this seems to suggest that $f(x,y)$ would necessarily have conditionals
$f(x \mid y)$ and $f(y \mid x)$. If this were true, then we would have the
explicit formula for the joint:

$$
  f(x,y) = \frac{f(y \mid x)}{\int \frac{f(y \mid x)}{f(x \mid y)} \ dy}.
$$

However, I can't see any reason in particular that we would have

$$
  \frac{f(y \mid x)}{\int \frac{f(y \mid x)}{f(x \mid y)} \ dy}
  = 
  \frac{f(x \mid y)}{\int \frac{f(x \mid y)}{f(y \mid x)} \ dx}
$$

given only the assumptions listed above.

So where am I going wrong? Am I not assuming enough to get a stationary
distribution, and if the stationary distribution does exist why does it seem to
point me in the direction of something that I don't think should work?